# How to Add Fira Code: monospaced font with programming ligatures in NetBeans IDE 8.1?

Tags: netbeans-8

How to Add Fira Code: monospaced font with programming ligatures in NetBeans IDE 8.1?

I searched around, all I found was that it was possible and that it works, but not how.

I already managed to change the font, but the ligatures don't work.

Answer (score 5):

Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Syntax - Default - Font: - add Fira Code

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Throwing this here in case somebody hits this on their first step of the journey. I'm on Netbeans 8.2 (vs 8.1) Windows 10. My fonts would not show after installing them. I had to manually copy the font files to the C:\Windows\Fonts\ folder by an elevated command prompt. Credit goes to this guy -> [skomisa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112673/newly-installed-fonts-do-not-appear-in-netbeans/55130224#55130224)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently for font ligatures to work you need the latest development builds rather than the stable 8.1 release.

However, whilst people seem to have success with this, I still cannot get it to work with either the latest Fira Code or Hasklig fonts.

Give the latest dev nightly a shot and tell m if it works for you.

Comment: I'll give it a shot once I'm at work again, thanks for the info.

Comment: any luck ? I think there might be an issue on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

To install the font file, you can zip the .ttf file and load it with tools> options import.