# Newly installed fonts do not appear in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, fonts, installation

I am trying to add new fonts to my Netbeans editor by downloading them and double-clicking the .ttf files and pressing 'Install' on the upper left corner. I am able to install the fonts with no issues. However, when I reload Netbeans and go to select the new font, it does not appear on the list of available fonts. Restarting Windows doesn't help. Has anyone had this issue before? And if so, we you able to fix it and how?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am using Netbeans 10.

EDIT2: I am trying to install Roboto Mono and Inconsolata, here are the links to the downloads:

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono

Get back to me if you have any luck, thank you.

Comment: Which fonts _do_ show up in the list of available fonts? Possible it only shows monospaced fonts as candidates?

Comment: Please update your question with the specific font(s) giving you the problem (and a link for the download), so that others can try to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Initially I had the same problem as you. After installing the new fonts and rebooting, those new fonts were not available in NetBeans 10.0, even though they were available in other applications such as Firefox and Notepad.

In my case, installing the ***.ttf** files resulted in them being installed in a user specific folder: `C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`.

However, after I copied (only) the ***.ttf** files for **Inconsolata** from that folder to **C:\Windows\Fonts** and rebooted again, the **Inconsolata** font was visible in NetBeans 10.0. Here is a screen shot showing the use of **Inconsolata** font:

[image: setfont]

Notes:

- I don't know why this action was necessary. I'm pretty sure I have installed other fonts for NetBeans in the past that didn't require manually copying them to `C:\Windows\Fonts`.
- This issue isn't specific to NetBeans 10.0 for those particular fonts; it also exists in NetBeans 8.2.
- Don't use Windows File Explorer for copying the fonts since it treats `C:\Windows\Fonts` in a special way. Instead, copy the ***.ttf** files to `C:\Windows\Fonts` using **copy** from the command line:
  [image: setFont2]
- I'm not sure whether this is a NetBeans issue or a Windows 10 issue, but since other software picked up the new fonts from the user directory perhaps this is a NetBeans bug?

Comment: "Don't use Windows File Explorer for copying the fonts since it treats C:\Windows\Fonts in a special way. Instead" -- This part was my issue. Thanks!

Comment: This issue still exists for Netbeans 12!

Comment: You may not have permission to copy your *.ttf files to C:\Windows\Fonts using command prompt. Try run your command prompt as Administrator (Windows + X -> Command Prompt (Admin)) will give you the privilege needed.

Comment: There's a clean way to do this: Use Explorer to navigate to the folder where your TTF files are stored. Then right click on each single ttf file and choose "Install for all users".

Comment: @RenéPöpperl OK. I wasn't aware of that, and it certainly is a cleaner approach. If you post it as an answer I'll be happy to upvote.

Comment: @RenéPöpperl I upvoted your answer as well. Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in previous answers, NetBeans only shows up fonts that are installed globally (for all users).

If you just use „install“ from the context menu in Explorer or from the font preview window, the font is installed on a per-user basis and is not installed globally.

You don’t have to move the font files manually. There's a clean way to do this: Use Explorer to navigate to the folder where your TTF files are stored. Then right click on a ttf file and choose "Install for all users".

Answer (score 3):

1. Run command `cd "c:\Windows\Fonts"`
2. Force delete all fira fonts `del f/ firacode-regular.ttf`

   - (in my case, I had this font installed before, which is the one I want to use, so I will have to remove it to continue with the explanation)
3. Copy .ttf font file `copy "c:\users\mrconejO07\desktop\firacode-regular.ttf" "c:\windows\fonts"`

   - (in my case these are the paths where my file is and where it must be copied)
4. In theory it should work in the NetBeans IDE, enter to verify that the font should already appear in the options menu and if you see strange symbols when selecting the font you should ...
5. Open the .ttf file of the font you want to install and install it, now if it should work correctly.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9iJJ.png)