# Korean does not appear in Apache Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, unicode

i am pretty much tried all method to fix this but i didn't succeeded i dont really konw what to do
[how its look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7rom.png)

i tried endcoding to utf-8 and its didnt work
and chance the config file and stil didn't work
all work fine but when i put any korean char its just showing the square box 
and not showing the char himself.

Comment: Please show a minimal working example of your code and state a question that is answerable. The file doesn't show anything that is of value for someone trying to help you.

Comment: is nothing to show its just dont cant Convert to Korean letters and instead showing boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3/15/20: Edited to provide instructions on obtaining an appropriate font for Korean characters.
3/16/20: Edited to provide instructions on downloading, installing and using a Korean font collection.

---

The square boxes are probably being displayed because you are not using a font capable of rendering Korean characters, so just use one that does. One such font which NetBeans provides is **Arial Unicode MS** so try that:

1. To set that font for your edit windows containing your source code:

   - Select **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors**
   - On the **Syntax** tab set **Font** to **Arial Unicode MS**.
   - Click the **Apply** button, then the **OK** button.
   - To verify that the change allows Korean characters to be rendered, copy and paste this text into the `main()` method of some trivial Java application: `System.out.println("안녕하세요 세상!");`. If you have set the font to **Arial Unicode MS** it should be displayed correctly.
2. To also set that font for your **Output** window, containing the `println()` output:

   - Select **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous**
   - On the **Output** tab set **Font** to **Arial Unicode MS**.
   - Click the **Apply** button, then the **OK** button.

When you run your application you should see the Korean characters correctly rendered in the edit window and the output window:
[image: Korean font]

If this doesn't resolve your issue, please update your question to provide more specific details of your problem, including specifying the font(s) that your are using in the window(s) rendering Korean characters as square boxes.

---

If **Arial Unicode MS** is not available, select an alternative available font which is capable of rendering Korean characters. To do this on Windows:

- Open a **Command Prompt** window and enter `chcp 949` to change the code page to 949.
- Click the *command prompt* icon in the top left of the window, then select **Properties** from the context menu.
- Click the **Font** tab. The list in the **Font** panel will be restricted to those available fonts which support code page 949.
- In NetBeans set the font to one of those fonts which was available in the **Command Prompt** window for code page 949.
- If you need to add a font to NetBeans to support Korean characters, see this SO question: [Newly installed fonts do not appear in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55112673/2985643).

---

Another alternative approach is:

- [Download a Korean font collection](https://allyourfonts.com/font/gungsuh-font/) to a local file named **Gungsuh-Font.zip**. The collection contain four fonts: *Gungsuh*, *GungsuhChe*, *Batang* and *BatangChe*.
- Make that font collection available in edit windows in NetBeans: **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors**, then click **Import...**.
- Make that font collection available in the Output window in NetBeans : **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous**, click the **Ouput** tab, then click **Import...**.
- Set the font in the edit windows and/or the Output window to any of the newly installed fonts as previously described above for **Arial Unicode MS** font.
- Here's sample output, with the edit window using the fixed width *GungsuhChe*   font, and the Output window using *Batang* font:

  [image: KoreanFontCollection]

To use the fonts outside of NetBeans you need to install them on Windows:

- In Windows File Explorer locate and unzip the downloaded font file (**Gungsuh-Font.zip**).
- Select the unzipped file **gungsuh.ttc**, right click and select **Install** from the context menu to install the font collection to **C:\Windows\Fonts**.

You can then access the fonts outside of NetBeans. For example, here is a screen shot showing the Java application being run from the command line, with the font in the **Command Prompt** window first having been set to *BatangChe*:

[image]

Note from the screen shot that you must first set the code page to 949 (using `chcp 949`) before running the application, or the Korean characters will not be rendered correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have Arial Unicode MS option to choose i already try this.(btw i am using netbeans 11 but tried it even on netbeans 8.2)
 i changed the  regtion unicode to Korean i am using monospaced in the conifg i am using ms949 encoding

Comment: the problem is like i said i using the window encoding for korean letters but only in netbenas its show the boxes( for emxpale in Visual Studio the korean letters can be displayed)

Comment: @Dipi OK. It looks like [Microsoft changed their policy on providing Arial Unicode MS](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-word/arial-unicode-ms-font-missing/3d389ec7-dfaa-4002-adfd-5b1491cea8a1/). I have updated my answer accordingly, to provide more information on how to use an alternative font that supports Korean characters in NetBeans.

Comment: MS gothic is what i choosed for example but still dont work .
don't know why

Comment: @Dipi OK. I have updated the answer with another alternative approach, with detailed instructions on how to download, install and use a collection of Korean fonts within NetBeans, and also on Windows.