# Netbeans doesn't see newly installed fonts

Tags: netbeans, fonts, netbeans-12

I have installed several fonts (UbuntuMono, Dina, EnvyCode, etc...) and every editor (Notepad++, Word, etc...) see them.

Only Netbeans (version 12.0) cannot see them, even after reboot.

Where could I find the solution?

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112673/newly-installed-fonts-do-not-appear-in-netbeans).
It works perfectly.