# NetBeans 15 Hindi Character Display Issue

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-15

I upgraded NetBeans from Version 11 to 15. Version 15 is not displaying Hindi characters.

[image]

But Version 15 displays other language characters:

[image]

Under options, I have the same Fonts & Colors settings defined as Version 11.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks,

Brandon

Comment: In your edit window you need to use a font that can render Hindi text, and _Monospaced_ cannot do that; I tried using NetBeans 11 and NetBeans 15. However, if you change the font to _Nirmala UI_ or _Akshar Unicode_ or _Arial Unicode MS_ or _Unifont_ the text will render. Of those, only _Unifont_ is a fixed width font, so that may be your best option for an immediate fix. A better long term approach would be to download and install a fixed width font that supports all of the languages used in your source in NetBeans. Once you find a solution please post an answer here.

Comment: Hi skomisa, I've installed Netbeans 15 from the Zip file to make it Portable. My installation doesn't have Unifont. Also my JDK is version 19. Would those two combinations prevent any UTF-8 character rendering?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: OK. [1] My bad then - I guess I must have manually added Unifont in the past. Since you don't already have it you can just download it and add it yourself. Lots of sites offer it for free. [2] There have been issues with console rendering that have been both fixed and caused by JDK 18/19. I will test that later, but rendering the glyphs in your edit window (your primary concern?) shouldn't be affected by your JDK.

Comment: I updated my answer to show that everything still works for me when using JDK version _19+36-2238_, with the font for _All Languages_ set to _Arial Unicode MS_. I also installed NB 15 from the zip, so if you still have problems try this: [1] Close all edit windows. [2] Set your font for _All Languages_ to _Arial Unicode MS_. [3] Restart NetBeans. [4] Open a Java file in your edit window and copy/paste the Japanese and Hindi text from my answer below. Are the Japanese and Hindi characters still not rendering correctly?

Comment: Also, although it's not directly relevant for your question, for the Hindi/Japanese text to render correctly in the **Output** window on Windows you must check _"Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"_ (_Region > Administrative > Change system locale...._ in Control Panel) if using JDK 19. A restart is also required. That setting wasn't necessary when using JDK 11. However, none of that is relevant for properly rendering the text in the edit window; for that you just need an appropriate font.

Comment: Skomisa, I sincerely thank you for the time you've been helping me. Since my Netbeans 15 portable installation doesn't have the Arial Unicode MS font you mention, where can I download it?  I want to duplicate exactly what you've done so I can verify I get the same results.  Thanks again for your help; I don't take it for granted!

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and (like you) I installed NetBeans 15 from the downloaded zip file. Arial Unicode MS was available automatically for me; I didn't take any special action to add it. What is your operating system?

Comment: I too am using Windows 10.  So I'm guessing Netbeans displays fonts available in Windows?

Comment: OK. I think the fonts available on a particular NetBeans installation should be a hybrid of fonts supplied by NetBeans and those already existing in directory **C:/Windows/Fonts**, but there may be some issues. Regardless, if you _globally_ install any font on your machine, it should be possible to make that font available to NetBeans, though the process is not necessarily completely straightforward. See [Newly installed fonts do not appear in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55112673/2985643) for more details of the problem, workarounds and solutions.

Comment: You are right. Surprisingly, it seems that Windows 10 does not include _Arial Unicode MS_! My machine is old, and may only have it because it was upgraded from Windows 8, and/or I used to have a copy Microsoft Office installed. Anyway, you can download MS Arial Unicode yourself from many sites (e.g. https://www.fonts100.com/font+5092_Arial+Unicode+MS.html), but be cautious when using those sites! Once you have unzipped the download, [follow the instructions here to install it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68342647/2985643), then restart NetBeans and _MS Arial Unicode_ should be available.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the font for the NetBeans **Edit** window to *Unifont* using **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Font** then it will render Latin, Japanese and Hindi characters. You don't specify the language(s) you are using, but here is a trivial sample application in Java:

```
package pkg;

public class HindiJapanese {

    public static void main(String[] args) { // Edit window uses Unifont font.
        System.out.println("Hello World!");        
        System.out.println("Hello world in Hindi:    नमस्ते दुनिया");
        System.out.println("Hello world in Japanese: こんにちは世界");
    }
    
}
```

You will also need to set the font for the **Output** window to *Unifont* using **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Output > Font** before running that code:

[image: Screen shot]

Update: Everything still works when using JDK 19 and *Arial Unicode MS* font, although that font is not fixed width:

[image: Using Arial Unicode MS with JDK 19]

Notes:

- My environment is a NetBeans 15 Java Ant project on Windows 10 using JDK 11.0.12, though the edit window font setting is language independent.
- In Control Panel the checkbox for *Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support* (**Region > Administrative > Change system locale....**) was not checked.
- *Unifont* is an impressive font. It <s>is bundled with NetBeans, it</s> can render [all characters in the BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), and was the only fixed width font I could find to render Latin, Japanese and Hindi text. Though not great visually, it seems acceptable for software development requiring different character sets from multiple languages.
- I can't vouch for the quality of the rendering of the Japanese and Hindi glyphs. See the [**Status** section of this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Unifont) for more information on *Unifont*, and some cautions on its limitations.
- While not directly related to your question, you might consider moving that language specific data out of your source code and into resource files if possible.